# Ionic 3 display each object in different page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to know and if I'm doing the right thing. I have an object below. What I want is to loop in each document to display it individually.

I want to know if creating a dynamic page is the right way. Or just use one page and iterate it there.

Although I don't have idea on how to code it yet.

```
[
    {
        "text": "This will be displayed in a page/display"
    },
    {
        "text": "This will be displayed separately"
    },
    {
        "text": "This will be displayed separately also."
    }
]
```

Currently, I got all the object right when the page load, but it displays all objects.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.http.get('assets/howIGotHere.json')
    .map( response => response.json())
    .subscribe( data => console.log(data ))
  }
```

Comment: What exactly u want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned that you want to loop in each document to display it individually, you can open each document in new page using following code. This UX will not be very user friendly. I would suggest you to list all text items in an `ion-list` and on clicking `ion-list` item push `Details Page`

> ParentPage.ts

```
class ParentPage{

 constructor(public navCtrl:NavController){
 }

ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.http.get('assets/howIGotHere.json')
    .map( response => response.json())
    .subscribe( data => {
        console.log(data);
        data.foreach(item=>{
            //Push a new page with text(i.e. item) passed as navparam
            this.navCtrl.push(DetailsPage,{pagetext:item});
        })
    })
}
```

}

> DetailsPage.ts

```
class DetailsPage{

     //Text to be displayed on HTML page
     pageText;

     constructor(public navParams:NavParams){

         //Assign nav params value to pageText
         this.pageText=this.navParams.get('text')
    }
 }
```